# How to rewrite URL with trailing slash in IIS

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have currently the problem, that I want to rewrite an URL from the root folder in my IIS web.config file. My configuration looks now like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="phpmyadmin" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)phpmyadmin(.*)" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/test/{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Installed is also phpMyAdmin, as you can see in the config. It will be seperated because I do have the following file structure:

- *wwwroot* (Root)

  - *phpmyadmin*

    - index.php
  - *test* (Default landing page)

    - *subtest*

      - index.html
    - index.html

When the user types in a URL like `http://localhost/` he should get rewrite actually to `http://localhost/test`. If he types `http://localhost/subtest/` then he should get the rewrite to `http://localhost/test/subtest`.

This already works with the script. But the problem is now that I can't type `http://localhost/subtest` (the trailing slash is missing) and get also a rewrite to `http://localhost/test/subtest`. Instead, I get redirected to `http://localhost/test/subtest` and of course it would not find the folder, because the root still remains from the `test` folder.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tryouts, I got now a workaround on how to solve it. Now I am checking if the URL has been called with the test folder in first place. If this is the case, it would redirect to the correct URL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="phpmyadmin" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)phpmyadmin(.*)" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^test/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/test/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```